# Laravel language file error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''as'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']'

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am getting following error when switch to **nl** language in Laravel.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''as''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']' (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\lovebnb\resources\views\my-property\index.blade.php)
>
> Exception message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''as''
>   (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ']'

My language file code is here:

```
<?php
    return [
        'property-types' => [
            'apartment' => 'Appartement',
            'bed-and-breakfast' => 'Bed en breakfast',
            'boutique-hotel' => 'Boutique hotel',
            'luxury-hotel' => 'Luxe hotel',
            'design-hotel' => 'Design hotel',
            'spa-hotel' => 'Spa hotel',
            'holiday-home' => 'Vakantiehuisje',
            'finca' => 'Finca',
            'loft' => 'Loft',
            'sleep-at-the-farmer' => 'Slapen bij de boer',
            'resort' => 'Resort',
            'lodge' => 'Lodge',
            'villa' => 'Villa',
            'chalet' => 'Chalet',
            'luxury-tent-or-yurt' => 'Luxe tent of yurt',
            'castle' => 'Kasteel',
            'country-house' => 'Landhuis',
            'guesthouse' => 'Pension',
            'other' => 'Overige',
        ],
        'countries' => [
            'al' => 'Albanië',
            'ad' => 'Andorra',
            'am' => 'Armenië',
            'at' => 'Oostenrijk',
            'az' => 'Azerbeidzjan',
            'by' => 'Wit-Rusland',
            'be' => 'België',
            'ba' => 'Bosnië en Herzegovina',
            'bg' => 'Bulgarije',
            'hr' => 'Kroatië',
            'cy' => 'Cyprus',
            'cz' => 'Tsjechië',
            'dk' => 'Denemarken',
            'ee' => 'Estland',
            'fi' => 'Finland',
            'fr' => 'Frankrijk',
            'ge' => 'Georgië',
            'de' => 'Duitsland',
            'gr' => 'Griekenland',
            'hu' => 'Hongarije',
            'is' => 'IJsland',
            'ie' => 'Ierland',
            'it' => 'Italië',
            'kz' => 'Kazachstan',
            'xk' => 'Kosovo',
            'lv' => 'Letland',
            'li' => 'Liechtenstein',
            'lt' => 'Litouwen',
            'lu' => 'Luxemburg',
            'mk' => 'Macedonië',
            'mt' => 'Malta',
            'md' => 'Moldavië',
            'mc' => 'Monaco',
            'me' => 'Montenegro',
            'nl' => 'Nederland',
            'no' => 'Noorwegen',
            'pl' => 'Polen',
            'pt' => 'Portugal',
            'ro' => 'Roemenië',
            'ru' => 'Rusland',
            'sm' => 'San Marino',
            'rs' => 'Servië',
            'sk' => 'Slowakije',
            'si' => 'Slovenië',
            'es' => 'Spanje',
            'se' => 'Zweden',
            'ch' => 'Zwitserland',
            'tr' => 'Turkije',
            'ua' => 'Oekraïne',
            'en' => 'Verenigd Koninkrijk',
            'va' => 'Vaticaanstad',
            'af' => 'Afghanistan',
            'ax' => 'Aland eilanden',
            'dz' => 'Algerije',
            'as' => 'Amerikaans Samoa',
            'ao' => 'Angola',
            'ai' => 'Anguilla',
            'aq' => 'Antarctica',
            'ag' => 'Antigua en Barbuda',
            'ar' => 'Argentina',
            'aw' => 'Aruba',
            'au' => 'Australië',
            'bs' => 'Bahamas',
            'bh' => 'Bahrain',
            'bd' => 'Bangladesh',
            'bb' => 'Barbados',
            'bz' => 'Belize',
            'bj' => 'Benin',
            'bm' => 'Bermuda',
            'bt' => 'Bhutan',
            'bo' => 'Bolivia plurinational state of',
            'bq' => 'Bonaire sint eustatius en saba',
            'bw' => 'Botswana',
            'bv' => 'Bouvet island',
            'br' => 'Brazilië',
            'io' => 'Britse Indische Oceaan Gebied',
            'bn' => 'Brunei darussalam',
            'bf' => 'Burkina faso',
            'bi' => 'Burundi',
            'kh' => 'Cambodja',
            'cm' => 'Kameroen',
            'ca' => 'Canada',
            'cv' => 'Cape verde',
            'ky' => 'Cayman Eilanden',
            'cf' => 'Centraal-Afrikaanse republiek',
            'td' => 'Chad',
            'cl' => 'Chile',
            'cn' => 'China',
            'cx' => 'kerst eiland',
            'cc' => 'Cocos (keeling) eilanden',
            'co' => 'Colombia',
            'km' => 'Comoros',
            'cg' => 'Congo',
            'cd' => 'Congo de democratische republiek van de',
            'ck' => 'Cook Islands',
            'cr' => 'Costa rica',
            'ci' => 'Cate d ivoire',
            'cu' => 'Cuba',
            'cw' => 'Curaã§ao',
            'dj' => 'Djibouti',
            'dm' => 'Dominica',
            'do' => 'Dominicaanse republiek',
            'ec' => 'Ecuador',
            'bv' => 'Egypte',
            'sv' => 'El salvador',
            'gq' => 'Equatoriaal-Guinea',
            'er' => 'Eritrea',
            'et' => 'Ethiopië',
            'fk' => 'Falkland eilanden (malvinas)',
            'fo' => 'Faroe Islands',
            'fj' => 'Fiji',
            'gf' => 'Frans Guiana',
            'pf' => 'Frans-Polynesië',
            'tf' => 'Franse zuidelijke gebieden',
            'ga' => 'Gabon',
            'gm' => 'Gambia',
            'gh' => 'Ghana',
            'gi' => 'Gibraltar',
            'gl' => 'Groenland',
            'gd' => 'Grenada',
            'gp' => 'Guadeloupe',
            'gu' => 'Guam',
            'gt' => 'Guatemala',
            'gg' => 'Guernsey',
            'gn' => 'Guinea',
            'gw' => 'Guinea-Bissau',
            'gy' => 'Guyana',
            'ht' => 'Haiti',
            'hm' => 'Hoorde eiland en mcdonald eilanden',
            'va' => 'Heilige zee (Vaticaanstadstaat)',
            'hn' => 'Honduras',
            'hk' => 'Hong Kong',
            'in' => 'India',
            'id' => 'Indonesië',
            'ir' => 'Iran, islamitische republiek van',
            'iq' => 'Iraq',
            'im' => 'Eiland van de mens',
            'il' => 'Israël',
            'jm' => 'Jamaica',
            'jp' => 'Japan',
            'je' => 'Jersey',
            'jo' => 'Jordanië',
            'ke' => 'Kenya',
            'ki' => 'Kiribati',
            'kp' => 'Korea, democratische volkerenrepubliek',
            'kr' => 'Korea, republiek van',
            'kw' => 'Koeweit',
            'kg' => 'Kirgizië',
            'la' => 'Democratische republiek Laos',
            'lb' => 'Libanon',
            'ls' => 'Lesotho',
            'lr' => 'Liberia',
            'ly' => 'Libië',
            'mo' => 'Macao',
            'mk' => 'Macedonië, de voormalige Joegoslavische Republiek',
            'mg' => 'Madagascar',
            'mw' => 'Malawi',
            'my' => 'Maleisië',
            'mv' => 'Maldiven',
            'ml' => 'Mali',
            'mh' => 'Marshall Islands',
            'mq' => 'Martinique',
            'mr' => 'Mauritania',
            'mu' => 'Mauritius',
            'yt' => 'Mayotte',
            'mx' => 'Mexico',
            'fm' => 'Micronesia, federale staten van',
            'md' => 'Moldavië, republiek',
            'mn' => 'Mongolië',
            'ms' => 'Montserrat',
            'ma' => 'Marokko',
            'mz' => 'Mozambique',
            'mm' => 'Myanmar',
            'na' => 'Namibia',
            'nr' => 'Nauru',
            'np' => 'Nepal',
            'nc' => 'New caledonia',
            'nz' => 'Nieuw Zeeland',
            'ni' => 'Nicaragua',
            'ne' => 'Niger',
            'ng' => 'Nigeria',
            'nu' => 'Niue',
            'nf' => 'Norfolk island',
            'mp' => 'Noord-Mariana Eilanden',
            'om' => 'Oman',
            'pk' => 'Pakistan',
            'pw' => 'Palau',
            'ps' => 'Palestijnse staat',
            'pa' => 'Panama',
            'pg' => 'Papua Nieuw-Guinea',
            'py' => 'Paraguay',
            'pe' => 'Peru',
            'ph' => 'Philippines',
            'pn' => 'Pitcairn',
            'pr' => 'Puerto rico',
            'qa' => 'Qatar',
            're' => 'Rã unie',
            'ru' => 'Russische Federatie',
            'rw' => 'Rwanda',
            'bl' => 'Saint barthã © lemy',
            'sh' => 'Heilige helena, hemelvaart en tristan da cunha',
            'kn' => 'Saint Kitts and Nevis',
            'lc' => 'Saint Lucia',
            'mf' => 'Saint martin (frans deel)',
            'pm' => 'Saint pierre en miquelon',
            'vc' => 'Saint vincent en de grenadines',
            'ws' => 'Samoa',
            'st' => 'Sao tome en principe',
            'sa' => 'Saoedi-Arabië',
            'sn' => 'Senegal',
            'sc' => 'Seychellen',
            'sl' => 'Sierra leone',
            'sg' => 'Singapore',
            'sx' => 'Sint maarten (nederlands deel)',
            'sb' => 'Solomon Islands',
            'zo' => 'Somalië',
            'za' => 'Zuid-Afrika',
            'gs' => 'Zuid-Georgië en de zuid-sandwich-eilanden',
            'ss' => 'Zuid-Soedan',
            'lk' => 'Sri lanka',
            'sd' => 'Sudan',
            'sr' => 'Suriname',
            'sj' => 'Svalbard en jan mayen',
            'sz' => 'Swaziland',
            'sy' => 'Syrische Arabische Republiek',
            'tw' => 'Taiwan provincie china',
            'tj' => 'Tajikistan',
            'tz' => 'Tanzania verenigde republiek van',
            'th' => 'Thailand',
            'tl' => 'Timor-leste',
            'tg' => 'Togo',
            'tk' => 'Tokelau',
            'to' => 'Tonga',
            'tt' => 'Trinidad en Tobago',
            'tn' => 'Tunesië',
            'tm' => 'Turkmenistan',
            'tc' => 'Turks en Caicos Islands',
            'tv' => 'Tuvalu',
            'ug' => 'Uganda',
            'ae' => 'Verenigde Arabische emiraten',
            'gb' => 'Verenigd koninkrijk',
            'us' => 'Verenigde staten',
            'um' => 'Verenigde Staten kleine afgelegen eilanden',
            'uy' => 'Uruguay',
            'uz' => 'Oezbekistan',
            'vu' => 'Vanuatu',
            've' => 'Venezuela, Bolivariaanse Republiek',
            'vn' => 'Viet nam',
            'vg' => 'Virgin Islands, British',
            'vi' => 'Maagd eilanden, u.s.',
            'wf' => 'Wallis en futuna',
            'eh' => 'Western sahara',
            'ye' => 'Yemen',
            'zm' => 'Zambia',
            'zw' => 'Zimbabwe',
        ],
        'credit-card-types' => [
            'american-express' => 'American Express',
            'euro-mastercard' => 'Euro/Mastercard',
            'jcb' => 'JCB',
            'discover' => 'Discover',
            'bankcard' => 'Bankcard',
            'visa' => 'Visa',
            'diners-club' => 'Diners Club',
            'maestro' => 'Maestro',
            'pin' => 'PIN',
        ],
        'food-types' => [
            'continental' => 'Continentaal',
            'merican' => 'Amerikaans',
            'buffet' => 'Buffet',
            'italian' => 'Italiaans',
            'english-irish' => 'Engels / Iers',
            'vegetarian' => 'Vegetarisch',
            'vegan' => 'Veganistisch',
            'halal' => 'Halal',
            'gluten-free' => 'Glutenvrij',
            'kosher' => 'Kosjer',
            'asian' => 'Aziatisch',
        ],
        'facilities' => [
            'non-smoking-rooms' => 'Rookvrije kamers',
            'non-smoking-entire-property' => 'Niet-roken in gehele accommodatie',
            'bar' => 'Bar',
            'meeting-room-banquet-hall' => 'Vergader- / feestzaal',
            'luggage-storage' => 'Bagageopslag',
            'restaurant-a-la-carte' => 'Restaurant (à la carte)',
            'fitness-room' => 'Fitnessruimte',
            'solarium' => 'Solarium',
            'indoor-swimming-pool-all-year' => 'Binnenzwembad (hele jaar)',
            'clothing-rack' => 'Kledingrek',
            'drying-rack-for-clothes' => 'Droogrek voor kleding',
            'folding-bed' => 'Inklapbaar bed',
            'toilet-paper' => 'Toiletpapier',
            'toilet-with-handles' => 'Toilet met handgrepen',
            'bath' => 'Bad',
        ],
        'languages' => [
            'nl' => 'Nederlands',
            'be' => 'Vlaams',
            'en' => 'Engels',
        ],
        'room-types' => [
            'single' => 'Eenpersoons',
            'double' => 'Tweepersoons',
            'twin' => 'Tweepersoons - 2 aparte bedden',
            'double-1-or-2-beds' => 'Tweepersoons (1 of 2 bedden)',
            'triple' => 'Driepersoons',
            'quad' => 'Vierpersoons',
            'family' => 'Familiekamer',
            'suite' => 'Suite',
            'studio' => 'Studio',
            'apartment' => 'Appartement',
        ],
        'bed-types' => [
            'single-90-130' => 'Eenpersoonsbed (90-130 cm)',
            'double-131-150' => 'Tweepersoonsbed (131-150 cm)',
            'double-151-180' => 'Tweepersoonsbed (151-180 cm)',
            'double-181-210' => 'Tweepersoonsbed (181-210 cm)',
            'bunk' => 'Stapelbed',
            'sofa' => 'Slaapbank',
        ],
    ];
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your `index.blade.php` view ?

Comment: This file is not calling in index file.

Comment: Then in which view are you calling this file ?

Comment: I am calling like this 

@lang('properties.property-types.'.$property->propertyType->name)

Comment: mmmh i keep thinking that the issue is coming from `my-property\index.blade.php`... (Because the log talk about it).